# Debian nagios3 web interface don't display all services

Tags: nagios

Using debian packaged 3.5.1 nagios version, web interface page "Current Status" -> "Services" don't display all services: It only display one host. And *sometimes*, only two services for this host. If i look at "Problems" -> "Services" i can see all problematic services. If i look at "View Service Details For This Host" view, i can see all services of a host. So problematic page is "Current Status" -> "Services".

Using "nagiosadmin" user. My config:

**/etc/nagios3/cgi.cfg**

```
main_config_file=/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg
physical_html_path=/usr/share/nagios3/htdocs
url_html_path=/nagios3
show_context_help=1
use_pending_states=1
nagios_check_command=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nagios /var/cache/nagios3/status.dat 5 '/usr/sbin/nagios3'
use_authentication=1
use_ssl_authentication=0
authorized_for_system_information=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_configuration_information=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_system_commands=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_services=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_hosts=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_service_commands=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_host_commands=nagiosadmin
default_statusmap_layout=5
default_statuswrl_layout=4
ping_syntax=/bin/ping -n -U -c 5 $HOSTADDRESS$
refresh_rate=90
result_limit=100
escape_html_tags=1
action_url_target=_blank
notes_url_target=_blank
lock_author_names=1
```

**/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg**

```
log_file=/var/log/nagios3/nagios.log
cfg_file=/etc/nagios3/commands.cfg
cfg_dir=/etc/nagios-plugins/config
cfg_dir=/etc/nagios3/conf.d
cfg_file=/etc/nagios3/contacts.cfg
object_cache_file=/var/cache/nagios3/objects.cache
precached_object_file=/var/lib/nagios3/objects.precache
resource_file=/etc/nagios3/resource.cfg
status_file=/var/cache/nagios3/status.dat
status_update_interval=10
nagios_user=nagios
nagios_group=nagios
check_external_commands=1
command_check_interval=-1
command_file=/var/lib/nagios3/rw/nagios.cmd
external_command_buffer_slots=4096
lock_file=/var/run/nagios3/nagios3.pid
temp_file=/var/cache/nagios3/nagios.tmp
temp_path=/tmp
event_broker_options=-1
log_rotation_method=d
log_archive_path=/var/log/nagios3/archives
use_syslog=1
log_notifications=1
log_service_retries=1
log_host_retries=1
log_event_handlers=1
log_initial_states=0
log_external_commands=1
log_passive_checks=1
service_inter_check_delay_method=s
max_service_check_spread=30
service_interleave_factor=s
host_inter_check_delay_method=s
max_host_check_spread=30
max_concurrent_checks=0
check_result_reaper_frequency=10
max_check_result_reaper_time=30
check_result_path=/var/lib/nagios3/spool/checkresults
max_check_result_file_age=3600
cached_host_check_horizon=15
cached_service_check_horizon=15
enable_predictive_host_dependency_checks=1
enable_predictive_service_dependency_checks=1
soft_state_dependencies=0
auto_reschedule_checks=0
auto_rescheduling_interval=30
auto_rescheduling_window=180
sleep_time=0.25
service_check_timeout=360
host_check_timeout=360
event_handler_timeout=360
notification_timeout=360
ocsp_timeout=5
perfdata_timeout=5
retain_state_information=1
state_retention_file=/var/lib/nagios3/retention.dat
retention_update_interval=60
use_retained_program_state=1
use_retained_scheduling_info=1
retained_host_attribute_mask=0
retained_service_attribute_mask=0
retained_process_host_attribute_mask=0
retained_process_service_attribute_mask=0
retained_contact_host_attribute_mask=0
retained_contact_service_attribute_mask=0
interval_length=60
check_for_updates=1
bare_update_check=0
use_aggressive_host_checking=0
execute_service_checks=1
accept_passive_service_checks=1
execute_host_checks=1
accept_passive_host_checks=1
enable_notifications=1
enable_event_handlers=1
process_performance_data=0
obsess_over_services=0
obsess_over_hosts=0
translate_passive_host_checks=0
passive_host_checks_are_soft=0
check_for_orphaned_services=1
check_for_orphaned_hosts=1
check_service_freshness=1
service_freshness_check_interval=60
service_check_timeout_state=c
check_host_freshness=0
host_freshness_check_interval=60
additional_freshness_latency=15
enable_flap_detection=1
low_service_flap_threshold=5.0
high_service_flap_threshold=20.0
low_host_flap_threshold=5.0
high_host_flap_threshold=20.0
date_format=iso8601
p1_file=/usr/lib/nagios3/p1.pl
enable_embedded_perl=1
use_embedded_perl_implicitly=1
illegal_object_name_chars=`~!$%^&*|'"<>?,()=
illegal_macro_output_chars=`~$&|'"<>
use_regexp_matching=0
use_true_regexp_matching=0
admin_email=sevajol.bastien@gmail.com
admin_pager=pageroot@localhost
daemon_dumps_core=0
use_large_installation_tweaks=0
enable_environment_macros=1
debug_level=0
debug_verbosity=1
debug_file=/var/log/nagios3/nagios.debug
max_debug_file_size=1000000
cfg_file=/etc/nagios3/templates.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios3/hosts.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios3/services.cfg
```

**/etc/nagios3/hosts.cfg**

```
define hostgroup{
        hostgroup_name  linux-servers ; The name of the hostgroup
        alias           Linux Servers ; Long name of the group
        members         localhost     ; Comma separated list of hosts that belong to this group
        }
define host{
  use linux-server
  host_name xxx
  alias xxx
  address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  contacts bux
}
define host{
  use linux-server
  host_name yyy 
  alias yyy
  address yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
  contacts bux
}
define host {
  use linux-server
  host_name zzz
  alias zzz
  address zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
  max_check_attempts 1 
  contacts bux
}
```

**/etc/nagios3/services.cfg**

```
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       localhost
        service_description             PING
    check_command           check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%
        }
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       localhost
        service_description             Disk space /
    check_command           check_local_disk!20%!10%!/
        }
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       localhost
        service_description             Disk space /home
        check_command                   check_local_disk!20%!10%!/home
        }
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       localhost
        service_description             Disk space /mnt/hdd1kc
        check_command                   check_local_disk!10%!5%!/mnt/hdd1kc
        }
[...]
```

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you describe are what happens when you have multiple Nagios daemons running at the same time. It then becomes a race condition for which one wrote the status file that the web UI is parsing and showing you.

Make sure you only have 1 Nagios instance running.

Comment: Hello, ``ps aux | grep nagios`` command return only one nagios process and one nrpe process.